# How to find complete set of incongruent primitive roots mod 17

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to find complete set of incongruent primitive roots  $\mod{17}$?

I tried to find the how many of these primitive root are there for  $\mod{17}$ by using this $\phi(\phi(17))$ = $\phi(16)$ = $\phi(2^4)$ = $2^3(2-1)=8$. So I found  $8$ primitive roots in the set to be found. My question is how do I proceed from here no words?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: try to find $qr$ and $qnr$.

Comment: How do I find them?

Answer (score 1):

Hint : If $r$ is a primitive root modulo $n$, then $r^a$ is a primitive root
       modulo $n$, if and only if $gcd(a,\phi(n))=1$